# What is generating the error 'Can't subset `.data` outside of a data mask context' with 'dplyr'?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a huge shiny app which uses a huge package. I'm not the author of any of them and I'm a bit lost. A function (`fermentationPlot`) throws the error: ***Can't subset `.data` outside of a data mask context***:

```
Warning: Error in fermentationPlot: Can't subset `.data` outside of a data mask context.
  185: <Anonymous>
  173: dplyr::arrange
  172: dplyr::mutate
  171: as.data.frame
```

What could be the cause of this error? What does it mean? Below is the code block which generates it. I googled this error message and I found that it can be fixed by downgrading 'dplyr'. I tried 1.0.10, 1.0.5 and 1.0.0, and the error always occurs.

```r
  plotInfo <- dplyr::left_join(
    x = dplyr::select(
      plotDefaults, -c(.data$templateName, .data$minValue, .data$maxValue)
    ), 
    y = plotSettings, 
    by = .data$dataName
  ) %>%
    dplyr::arrange(!is.na(.data$order), -.data$order) %>%
    dplyr::mutate(
      color = replace(.data$color, .data$color == "Blue", "Dark blue"),
      minValue = as.numeric(.data$minValue),
      maxValue = as.numeric(.data$maxValue)
    ) %>%
    as.data.frame()
```

Comment: `by = .data$dataName` is wrong

Comment: I think you're supposed to use `.data[["dataName"]]` instead of the `$` construction you have.

Comment: @DanAdams No, it's `by = "dataName"`.

Answer (score 4):

The `by` argument of `left_join` must be *a character vector* of column names. Probably the author wanted to do

```
by = "dataName"
```

and not

```
by = .data$dataName
```

Answer (score 0):

My situation was a bit niche, but the variable causing the problem was a data variable in the package itself, so could be referenced like so

```r
package_name::problematic_variable
```

that solved for me.